# PCT with US RO --- how to file the IDS?

Tags: pct, ids

Last month I filed a PCT application with the US as the receiving office, using EFS-web.  I uploaded everything (I think) correctly and paid my microentity fees.  I want to now file an information disclosure, using for SB08a.  Previously, for a US-only application, there's a drop down selection under "Category" for IDS documents. However, for my PCT application, this field is not an option, and nothing looks like it's the correct "document description" for an IDS and attachments.  Please Help.

Comment: Are you sure you need to file one before entering us national phase?

Comment: Nope.  I'm not sure at all, first PCT. [googling]  Ok, I think you are correct.  Found this: " for international applications, within three months of the date of entry of the national stage as set forth in 37 CFR 1.491 ".  Please confirm.  Thanks.  K.

Comment: You are correct. Until you enter the national stage (or alternatively file a national by-pass application) there is no need and no way to file an IDS.